# Add your own content to node

Tags: 7, hooks, nodes

I've created a module that adds custom content to a node; I'd like to display this custom content in the node view. I think `hook_node_view()` is the right hook to use, but my content doesn't get displayed.

what I got so far is the following code:

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL) {
$node->content['mymodule']['#items'][0] = array(
    'value' => theme('mymodule_output', array('mymodule_cid' => $node->mymodule_cid)),
    'summary' => '',
    'format' => 'full_html',
    'safe_value' => theme('mymodule_output', array('mymodule_cid' => $node->mymodule_cid)),
    'safe_summary' => '',
);
$node->content['mymodule']['#weight'] = 12; 
}
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The hook is correct, but `$node->content['mymodule']['#items'][0]` should at least contain one of these array indexes/properties: "[#markup](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#markup-attribute)" or "[#theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#theme)"; if you don't use one of them, Drupal will not output anything.

If the array indexes you use are for properties handled by your theme function, then you should use *#* at the beginning; for example "format" would become "#format" (the same is true for the other properties).

Anyway, there is no need to use "format" as you do (whatever meaning it has); the function just output HTML, as done in the example shown in the [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) example.

```
function hook_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $node->content['my_additional_field'] = array(
    '#markup' => $additional_field, 
    '#weight' => 10, 
    '#theme' => 'mymodule_my_additional_field',
  );
}
```

If you want some more concrete examples of that hook implementations, you can look at [book_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--book--book.module/function/book_node_view/7), [statistics_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--statistics--statistics.module/function/statistics_node_view/7), and [translation_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--translation--translation.module/function/translation_node_view/7).

```
function book_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
  if ($view_mode == 'full') {
    if (!empty($node->book['bid']) && empty($node->in_preview)) {
      $node->content['book_navigation'] = array(
        '#markup' => theme('book_navigation', array('book_link' => $node->book)), 
        '#weight' => 100,
      );
    }
  }

  if ($view_mode != 'rss') {
    book_node_view_link($node, $view_mode);
  }
}
```

As side note, I will add that you should use the *#* character only for properties, or you are going to confuse Drupal, which expects that character to be used only for properties.
In fact, [element_children()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/element_children/7), which returns the list of child elements of the element passed as argument, uses the following code:

```
  foreach ($elements as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === '' || $key[0] !== '#') {
      $children[$key] = $value;
      if (is_array($value) && isset($value['#weight'])) {
        $sortable = TRUE;
      }
    }
  }
```

As you see, elements whose key value starts with *#* are not taken to be child elements; differently, Drupal would not be able to handle a case like this one (the code is really implemented by a Drupal module, the Search module):

```
  $form['#action'] = url($action);
  // Record the $action for later use in redirecting.
  $form_state['action'] = $action;
  $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search-form';
  $form['module'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $module,
  );
  $form['basic'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('container-inline')),
  );
  $form['basic']['keys'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => $prompt, 
    '#default_value' => $keys, 
    '#size' => $prompt ? 40 : 20, 
    '#maxlength' => 255,
  );
  // processed_keys is used to coordinate keyword passing between other forms
  // that hook into the basic search form.
  $form['basic']['processed_keys'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => '',
  );
  $form['basic']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Search'),
  );
```

Are `$form['#action']` and `$form['basic']['submit']` child elements?

As another side note, I will add that `hook_view()` is invoked by Drupal only for the modules that implement a content type.
In fact, the implementations of that hook are invoked by [node_build_content()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_build_content/7) using the following code:

```
  // The 'view' hook can be implemented to overwrite the default function
  // to display nodes.
  if (node_hook($node, 'view')) {
    $node = node_invoke($node, 'view', $view_mode, $langcode);
  }
```

The code for [node_invoke()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_invoke/7) is the following one:

```
  if (node_hook($node, $hook)) {
    $base = node_type_get_base($node);
    $function = $base . '_' . $hook;
    return ($function($node, $a2, $a3, $a4));
  }
```

The code invokes `$hook` for the module implementing the content type of the node passed as argument.