# Commenting on each paragraph of node body

Tags: nodes

I want to provide this option in Drupal that users be able to put comment on each paragraph of an article beside putting comment on the whole article.

I use explode command to make an array which contains paragraphs:

```
$paragraphs = explode("<p>",render($content));
```

In order to put comment for the whole article I write:

```
print render($content['comments']);
```

I am trying to find the file where `$content` is defined, so I can add another array like `$content[]['paragraphcomments']` for comments for each paragraph of an article. Does anyone know in which file `$content` is defined. Also does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: FYI Never hack core https://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core

Comment: Thank you. So as I understood the only files I can change are the files inside Sites folder, Am I right?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should only change files you have created yourself. Changing files from contrib modules can create more or less the same problems as hacking core. Anyway, in most cases it's just not necessary because of the modular architecture of drupal. It's a good practice to create separate subfolders for contrib modules and for your own custom code inside sites/all/modules (or sites/YOURSITE/modules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$content`is defined in node.module in the function `template_preprocess_node()`.
You can add elements to the nodes content using `hook_node_view()`(D7) or `hook_nodeapi()` (D6).

See the accepted answer of [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10081/add-your-own-content-to-node) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much. So do you think I should write a module with hook_node_view function and add element to the node content or I can do that by changing node.module?

Comment: Don't hack core! Especially if it's not necessary. Create a module and use `hook_node_view()`.

Comment: I checked template_preprocess_node() function in node.module file. but I did not find what I am looking for. I want to know how $content['comments'] is defined, so with hook_node_view I can create a new field like $node->content['comment for each paragraph'] and define it the same way that $node->content['comments] is defined.but make it a 2 dimensional array, so users can put comment on each paragraph of a node body. I would really appreciate it if you can give me some info. Thank you

Comment: @mery This deserves a new question. I'm not quite sure about your approach. Anyway, this question already has an accepted answer, so you will probably get more attention when you create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a module and can use jquery to shown & insert comments within paragraphs. If you use jquery then you'd need to use Ajax. You should show comment paragraphs in accordion style and allow visitor to comment after expanding it.

You can see simple Drupal developer examples in the [example module](https://drupal.org/project/examples).